# how to check shape incompatability in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

i am new to python. i am learning lstm. whenever I try to apply fit model I get this error `ValueError: Shapes (2, 3) and (2, 173, 3) are incompatible`

Here is code to reproduce the error

````
epochs = 60
batch_size = 2
lstm_units = 100
dense_units = 50

datafile_Xtrain = '.../train_H.csv'
dfTrX = read_csv(datafile_Xtrain, header=0)
valuesTrX = dfTrX.values
num_observationsTrX = valuesTrX.shape[0]
num_timestampsTrX = valuesTrX.shape[1]
train_X = valuesTrX.reshape((num_observationsTrX, num_timestampsTrX, 1))

# -- Input Y training  -----
datafile_Ytrain = '.../H.csv'
dfTrY = read_csv(datafile_Ytrain, header=0)
dfTrY.fillna(0)
valuesTrY = dfTrY.values
num_observationsTrY = valuesTrY.shape[0]
num_classesTrY = valuesTrY.shape[1]
train_Y = valuesTrY.reshape((num_observationsTrY, num_classesTrY))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(lstm_units, input_shape=(num_timestampsTrX,1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(dense_units, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classesTrY , activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_X, train_Y ,epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0, validation_split=0.1,shuffle=False)
print('Model fit successfully')```
````

A screenshot of my variable explorer if that can help :
[image: I am also adding screenshot of my variable explorer]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to return sequences, e.g. `(2, 173, 3)`, but instead a 2D array, e.g. `(2, 3)`, like in a classification task, you need to set

```
return_sequences=False
```

In your LSTM layer.

Comment: I have performed some changes but still got same sort of error. My lstm model is......model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200, input_shape=(num_timestamps,1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(173, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(173, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy' ,optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# --- Fit model
history=model.fit(train_X, Y, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(test_X, test_Y),verbose=0)

Comment: ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_32 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 173]